# Symfony2: using twig variables inside (imported) javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

Let's say the variable is called 'myvar'. I can access its value in twig using `{{ myvar }}`.

I can also use it inside javascript code, if inside the same twig page, by doing

```
<script>
//some javascript code
myJSVar = {{ myvar }};
//other javascript code
</script>
```

The question is: if I import a js (e.g. I have a main.js where I put all the common js stuff) is there a way do the same?

I've read about a solution for CSS ([Symfony2: Use Twig variable in stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897950/symfony2-use-twig-variable-in-stylesheet)) which is a bit convoluted, and another point of reference might be here ([Using Twig as an Assetic filter for JavaScript in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033947/using-twig-as-an-assetic-filter-for-javascript-in-symfony2)). Any other options?

In practice what I need is passing a global variable, something that you'd find in config.yml. It's a path basically, which is different in production and in development.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572506/symfony2-twig-and-javascript . Besides, the "fastest" alternative solution you have (**despite not the cleverest**) is to extend your template and write an inline script. (Also, another possible exploit is to **embed** the file by passing the variables you need, despite it may create you many issues later)

Comment: I did not get that one, but meanwhile I indeed solved it as they suggest in the link you sent (second solution, which is perfect for my case). Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something like:

```
<div id="somediv" data-var="{{ myvar }}"></div>.
```

And then on you main.js:

```
var myJSVar = $('#somediv').data('var');
```